# RobotFrameWork how to close a pop-up

Tags: robotframework

I know how to select a frame.

```
Select Frame    css:iframe[id^="PopupBoxIframe_"]
```

but DevExpress opens a pop-up. And I don't know how to select that pop-up

It doesn't work with  Select Window, the id is `ctl00_aspxMasterPopup_PWH0T` and the Select Window searches for Title, Name or ... but no ID

Comment: what kind of popup it is?

Comment: it's a pop-up from a DevExpress page.

Comment: This is the ID: ctl00_aspxMasterPopup_PWH0T  but I can't seem to hit on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the solution. 
first you do an unselect, then a select, somehow that does the trick.

```
unselect frame
Select Frame    css:iframe[id^="PopupBoxIframe_"]
```