# RobotFrameWork: how to select a pop-up

Tags: robotframework

-sorry the previous title was wrong-

I know how to select a frame.
Select Frame    css:iframe[id^="PopupBoxIframe_"]

but DevExpress opens a **pop-up**. And I don't know how to select that pop-up

It doesn't work with **Select Window** somehow

Comment: you can edit previous one close/delete this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RobotFrameWork how to close a pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195789/robotframework-how-to-close-a-pop-up)

Comment: yeah i will do that. Can I raise the bounty for the answer on this question? I desperatly need a solution for this struggle/puzzle.

Comment: before thinking of bounty make your question complete for that read [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow this works:

```
unselect frame
Select Frame css:iframe[id^="PopupBoxIframe_"]
```

note: I needed to select a pop-up after a pop-up.
(or a pop-up within a pop-up however you call it)